# Mobile sidebar in TailwindCSS causing vertical scroll-bar due to added bottom padding

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I have this dashboard layout, created with TailwindCSS. When I open the sidebar in a mobile-size view it adds a padding to the bottom of the page, resulting in a vertical scroll-bar.

```js
$(function () {
    $('#open-mobile-menu').one('click', function () {
        $('#mobile-menu').toggleClass('hidden');
    });

    $('#open-mobile-menu').on('click', function () {
        anime({
            targets: '#mobile-menu',
            translateX: () => ["-100%", "0%"],
            easing: "easeInOutQuart"
        })
        $('#mobile-menu-overlay').fadeIn();
        $('#app').addClass('overflow-y-hidden');
    });

    $('#close-mobile-menu').on('click', function () {
        anime({
            targets: '#mobile-menu',
            translateX: () => ["0%", "-100%"],
            easing: "easeInOutQuart"
        })
        $('#mobile-menu-overlay').fadeOut();
        $('#app').removeClass('overflow-y-hidden');
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="h-full bg-white">
   <head>
      <link rel="preload" as="style" href="http://io/build/assets/app-75ccac5a.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://io/build/assets/app-75ccac5a.css" />
   </head>
   <body class="h-full">
      <div class="fixed inset-0 bg-gray-900/80 hidden" id="mobile-menu-overlay"></div>
      <div>
         <div class="relative z-50 hidden min-h-screen" role="dialog" aria-modal="true" id="mobile-menu">
            <div class="fixed inset-0 flex">
               <div class="relative mr-16 flex w-full max-w-xs flex-1">
                  <div class="absolute left-full top-0 flex w-16 justify-center pt-5">
                     <button type="button" class="-m-2.5 p-2.5" id="close-mobile-menu">
                        <span class="sr-only">
                        Close sidebar
                        </span>
                        <svg class="h-6 w-6 text-white" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                           <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12" />
                        </svg>
                     </button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flex grow flex-col gap-y-5 overflow-y-auto bg-gray-900 px-6 pb-2 ring-1 ring-white/10">
                     <div class="flex h-16 shrink-0 items-center">
                        <img class="h-8 w-auto" src="https://placehold.co/32x32">
                     </div>
                     <nav class="flex flex-1 flex-col">
                        <ul role="list" class="flex flex-1 flex-col gap-y-7">
                           <li>
                              <ul role="list" class="-mx-2 space-y-1">
                                 <li>
                                    <a href="http://io/test" class="text-gray-400 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-800 group flex gap-x-3 rounded-md p-2 text-sm leading-6 font-semibold">
                                       <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="h-6 w-6 shrink-0">
                                          <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M2.25 12l8.954-8.955c.44-.439 1.152-.439 1.591 0L21.75 12M4.5 9.75v10.125c0 .621.504 1.125 1.125 1.125H9.75v-4.875c0-.621.504-1.125 1.125-1.125h2.25c.621 0 1.125.504 1.125 1.125V21h4.125c.621 0 1.125-.504 1.125-1.125V9.75M8.25 21h8.25" />
                                       </svg>
                                       Dashboard
                                    </a>
                                 </li>
                              </ul>
                           </li>
                        </ul>
                     </nav>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="hidden lg:fixed lg:inset-y-0 lg:z-50 lg:flex lg:w-72 lg:flex-col">
            <div class="flex grow flex-col gap-y-5 overflow-y-auto bg-gray-900 px-6">
               <div class="flex h-16 shrink-0 items-center">
                  <img class="h-8 w-auto" src="https://placehold.co/32x32">
               </div>
               <nav class="flex flex-1 flex-col">
                  <ul role="list" class="flex flex-1 flex-col gap-y-7">
                     <li>
                        <ul role="list" class="-mx-2 space-y-1">
                           <li>
                              <a href="http://io/test" class="text-gray-400 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-800 group flex gap-x-3 rounded-md p-2 text-sm leading-6 font-semibold">
                                 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="h-6 w-6 shrink-0">
                                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M2.25 12l8.954-8.955c.44-.439 1.152-.439 1.591 0L21.75 12M4.5 9.75v10.125c0 .621.504 1.125 1.125 1.125H9.75v-4.875c0-.621.504-1.125 1.125-1.125h2.25c.621 0 1.125.504 1.125 1.125V21h4.125c.621 0 1.125-.504 1.125-1.125V9.75M8.25 21h8.25" />
                                 </svg>
                                 Dashboard
                              </a>
                           </li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                     <li class="mt-auto flex space-between items-center">
                        <div class="flex flex-shrink-0 py-4 w-full justify-between">
                           <a href="#" class="group block flex-shrink-0">
                              <div class="flex items-center">
                                 <div>
                                    <img class="inline-block h-9 w-9 rounded-full" src="https://placehold.co/36x36" alt="">
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="ml-3">
                                    <p class="text-sm font-medium text-white">Tom Cook</p>
                                    <p class="text-xs font-medium text-gray-300 group-hover:text-gray-200">
                                       View profile
                                    </p>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </a>
                           <div class="flex items-center justify-end">
                              <a href="#" class="text-gray-400 hover:text-white">
                                 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="w-6 h-6 block">
                                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M15.75 9V5.25A2.25 2.25 0 0013.5 3h-6a2.25 2.25 0 00-2.25 2.25v13.5A2.25 2.25 0 007.5 21h6a2.25 2.25 0 002.25-2.25V15m3 0l3-3m0 0l-3-3m3 3H9" />
                                 </svg>
                              </a>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </li>
                  </ul>
               </nav>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="fixed top-0 z-40 flex items-center gap-x-6 bg-gray-900 px-4 py-4 shadow-sm sm:px-6 lg:hidden min-w-full">
            <button type="button" class="-m-2.5 p-2.5 text-gray-400 lg:hidden" id="open-mobile-menu">
               <span class="sr-only">
               Open sidebar
               </span>
               <svg class="h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                  <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M3.75 6.75h16.5M3.75 12h16.5m-16.5 5.25h16.5" />
               </svg>
            </button>
            <div class="flex-1 text-sm font-semibold leading-6 text-white">Dashboard</div>
            <a href="#">
            <span class="sr-only">
            View your profile
            </span>
            <img class="h-8 w-8 rounded-full bg-gray-800" src="https://placehold.co/32x32" alt="">
            </a>
         </div>
         <main class="py-10 lg:pl-72">
            <div class="px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            </div>
         </main>
      </div>
      <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-3gJwYpMe3QewGELv8k/BX9vcqhryRdzRMxVfq6ngyWXwo03GFEzjsUm8Q7RZcHPHksttq7/GFoxjCVUjkjvPdw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.1/anime.min.js" integrity="sha512-z4OUqw38qNLpn1libAN9BsoDx6nbNFio5lA6CuTp9NlK83b89hgyCVq+N5FdBJptINztxn1Z3SaKSKUS5UP60Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

I have tried to:

- remove `py-10` from the content section, this resolves the issue but I also need that padding in the main content section of the layout.
- Changing `fixed` to `sticky` but this adds the content below the navbar when it expands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the `#mobile-menu` is taking up layout space. You'd need to look at transferring the `position: fixed` from `#mobile-menu`'s inner element to itself, like:

```js
$(function () {
    $('#open-mobile-menu').one('click', function () {
        $('#mobile-menu').toggleClass('hidden');
    });

    $('#open-mobile-menu').on('click', function () {
        anime({
            targets: '#mobile-menu',
            translateX: () => ["-100%", "0%"],
            easing: "easeInOutQuart"
        })
        $('#mobile-menu-overlay').fadeIn();
        $('#app').addClass('overflow-y-hidden');
    });

    $('#close-mobile-menu').on('click', function () {
        anime({
            targets: '#mobile-menu',
            translateX: () => ["0%", "-100%"],
            easing: "easeInOutQuart"
        })
        $('#mobile-menu-overlay').fadeOut();
        $('#app').removeClass('overflow-y-hidden');
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="h-full bg-white">
   <head>
      <link rel="preload" as="style" href="http://matchlytix.io/build/assets/app-75ccac5a.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://matchlytix.io/build/assets/app-75ccac5a.css" />
   </head>
   <body class="h-full">
      <div class="fixed inset-0 bg-gray-900/80 hidden" id="mobile-menu-overlay"></div>
      <div>
         <div class="fixed z-50 hidden w-full" role="dialog" aria-modal="true" id="mobile-menu">
            <div class="min-h-screen flex">
               <div class="relative mr-16 flex w-full max-w-xs flex-1">
                  <div class="absolute left-full top-0 flex w-16 justify-center pt-5">
                     <button type="button" class="-m-2.5 p-2.5" id="close-mobile-menu">
                        <span class="sr-only">
                        Close sidebar
                        </span>
                        <svg class="h-6 w-6 text-white" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                           <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12" />
                        </svg>
                     </button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flex grow flex-col gap-y-5 overflow-y-auto bg-gray-900 px-6 pb-2 ring-1 ring-white/10">
                     <div class="flex h-16 shrink-0 items-center">
                        <img class="h-8 w-auto" src="https://placehold.co/32x32" alt="Matchlytix">
                     </div>
                     <nav class="flex flex-1 flex-col">
                        <ul role="list" class="flex flex-1 flex-col gap-y-7">
                           <li>
                              <ul role="list" class="-mx-2 space-y-1">
                                 <li>
                                    <a href="http://matchlytix.io/test" class="text-gray-400 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-800 group flex gap-x-3 rounded-md p-2 text-sm leading-6 font-semibold">
                                       <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="h-6 w-6 shrink-0">
                                          <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M2.25 12l8.954-8.955c.44-.439 1.152-.439 1.591 0L21.75 12M4.5 9.75v10.125c0 .621.504 1.125 1.125 1.125H9.75v-4.875c0-.621.504-1.125 1.125-1.125h2.25c.621 0 1.125.504 1.125 1.125V21h4.125c.621 0 1.125-.504 1.125-1.125V9.75M8.25 21h8.25" />
                                       </svg>
                                       Dashboard
                                    </a>
                                 </li>
                              </ul>
                           </li>
                        </ul>
                     </nav>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="hidden lg:fixed lg:inset-y-0 lg:z-50 lg:flex lg:w-72 lg:flex-col">
            <div class="flex grow flex-col gap-y-5 overflow-y-auto bg-gray-900 px-6">
               <div class="flex h-16 shrink-0 items-center">
                  <img class="h-8 w-auto" src="https://placehold.co/32x32" alt="Matchlytix">
               </div>
               <nav class="flex flex-1 flex-col">
                  <ul role="list" class="flex flex-1 flex-col gap-y-7">
                     <li>
                        <ul role="list" class="-mx-2 space-y-1">
                           <li>
                              <a href="http://matchlytix.io/test" class="text-gray-400 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-800 group flex gap-x-3 rounded-md p-2 text-sm leading-6 font-semibold">
                                 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="h-6 w-6 shrink-0">
                                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M2.25 12l8.954-8.955c.44-.439 1.152-.439 1.591 0L21.75 12M4.5 9.75v10.125c0 .621.504 1.125 1.125 1.125H9.75v-4.875c0-.621.504-1.125 1.125-1.125h2.25c.621 0 1.125.504 1.125 1.125V21h4.125c.621 0 1.125-.504 1.125-1.125V9.75M8.25 21h8.25" />
                                 </svg>
                                 Dashboard
                              </a>
                           </li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                     <li class="mt-auto flex space-between items-center">
                        <div class="flex flex-shrink-0 py-4 w-full justify-between">
                           <a href="#" class="group block flex-shrink-0">
                              <div class="flex items-center">
                                 <div>
                                    <img class="inline-block h-9 w-9 rounded-full" src="https://placehold.co/36x36" alt="">
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="ml-3">
                                    <p class="text-sm font-medium text-white">Tom Cook</p>
                                    <p class="text-xs font-medium text-gray-300 group-hover:text-gray-200">
                                       View profile
                                    </p>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </a>
                           <div class="flex items-center justify-end">
                              <a href="#" class="text-gray-400 hover:text-white">
                                 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="w-6 h-6 block">
                                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M15.75 9V5.25A2.25 2.25 0 0013.5 3h-6a2.25 2.25 0 00-2.25 2.25v13.5A2.25 2.25 0 007.5 21h6a2.25 2.25 0 002.25-2.25V15m3 0l3-3m0 0l-3-3m3 3H9" />
                                 </svg>
                              </a>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </li>
                  </ul>
               </nav>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="fixed top-0 z-40 flex items-center gap-x-6 bg-gray-900 px-4 py-4 shadow-sm sm:px-6 lg:hidden min-w-full">
            <button type="button" class="-m-2.5 p-2.5 text-gray-400 lg:hidden" id="open-mobile-menu">
               <span class="sr-only">
               Open sidebar
               </span>
               <svg class="h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                  <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M3.75 6.75h16.5M3.75 12h16.5m-16.5 5.25h16.5" />
               </svg>
            </button>
            <div class="flex-1 text-sm font-semibold leading-6 text-white">Dashboard</div>
            <a href="#">
            <span class="sr-only">
            View your profile
            </span>
            <img class="h-8 w-8 rounded-full bg-gray-800" src="https://placehold.co/32x32" alt="">
            </a>
         </div>
         <main class="py-10 lg:pl-72">
            <div class="px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            </div>
         </main>
      </div>
      <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-3gJwYpMe3QewGELv8k/BX9vcqhryRdzRMxVfq6ngyWXwo03GFEzjsUm8Q7RZcHPHksttq7/GFoxjCVUjkjvPdw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.1/anime.min.js" integrity="sha512-z4OUqw38qNLpn1libAN9BsoDx6nbNFio5lA6CuTp9NlK83b89hgyCVq+N5FdBJptINztxn1Z3SaKSKUS5UP60Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```